# Can I transfer my Minecraft worlds from my PC Windows 7 laptop to my tablet?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have Minecraft and I want to transfer my Minecraft worlds from my Windows 7 Professional laptop to my tablet which has Craft Exploration Survival PE. Is this possible?

Comment: 'Craft Exploration Survival' is not even a Minecraft Game. There is literally no way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

**In short: *No***

The 'Minecraft' and 'Craft Exploration Survival PE' are 2 separate games and have to be treated as such. Thus their save-games are not compatible.